# Почему радио считает родителем виджет подключенный к layout? И как получить имя для соседнего объекта?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qradiobutton

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Radio(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__( 
        self, 
        parent=None,
    ):
        super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.radio_1 =QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self)
        self.radio_2 =QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio_1)
        lay.addWidget(self.radio_2)

class Child(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__( 
        self, 
        num="none",
        parent=None,
    ):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rad = Radio(self)
        self.setObjectName("child-{}".format(num))      
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent)
        self.label.setText("label-{}".format(num) )

        setattr(parent, "label-{}".format(num), self.label)

        self.label.setObjectName("label-{}".format(num))
        self.label.move(num*100, 11)

class Parent(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        main.setStyleSheet('background:red')
        main.setObjectName(u"main")
        main.resize(100, 100)
        main.move(50,50)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(main)

        self.group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)


        for x in range(2) :
            wid = Child(x, self)
            lay.addWidget(wid.rad)
            wid.rad.radio_1.setObjectName("radio_1-{}".format(x))
            wid.rad.radio_2.setObjectName("radio_2-{}".format(x))
            self.group.addButton(wid.rad.radio_1, 0)
            self.group.addButton(wid.rad.radio_2, 1)

        self.group.buttonToggled.connect(self.fun)
    def fun(self, but, state):
        if state:
            id = int(but.objectName().split('-')[1])
            wid = getattr(self, "label-{}".format(id))  
            print('{}->{}'.format( but.objectName(), wid.objectName()))

            wid = but.parent().parent()
            print('{}->{}'.format( but.objectName(), wid.objectName()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    par = Parent()
    par.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    par.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Да, я знаю, что он очень запутанный. Я просто использую его для экспериментов и для того, чтобы лучше понять как работает `child` и `parend` вложенные друг в друга объекты.

Вопрос в том, почему при запуске `радио` он считает своим родител `main`, а не `child-{}`

`super(Radio, self).__init__(parent)` назначает `Child()` своим родителем. или layout может перезаписывает родителя?

И как получить доступ к `label-{}` из функций `fun`

Упрощенная схема

```
Parent.Child-{1}.Radio.radio-{1}
#И 
Parent.Child-{1}.Radio.radio-{2}
#Активирует 
Parent.Child-{1}.label-{1}

#А
Parent.Child-{2}.Radio.radio-{1}
Parent.Child-{2}.Radio.radio-{2}
#Активирует 
Parent.Child-{2}.label-{2}

#Но 
Parent.Child-{1}.Radio.radio-{1}
#Почему-то активирует
Parent.main
```

Единственный способ который я знаю это записывать id в имя и после оброщатся к объекту по id.

Но мне кажется есть способ и получше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> почему при запуске радио он считает своим родитель `main` а не `child-{}`

потому что:

```
lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(main)       #  main
lay.addWidget(wid.rad)
```

---

> как получить доступ к `label-{}` из функций `fun`

попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MyRadio(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,):
        super(MyRadio, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("myRadio") 

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.radio_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(f'radio_1 <- ({parent.objectName()})') 
        self.radio_1.setObjectName(f'radio_1 <- ({parent.objectName()})')
        self.radio_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(f'radio_2 <- ({parent.objectName()})') 
        self.radio_2.setObjectName(f'radio_2 <- ({parent.objectName()})')

        self.lay.addWidget(self.radio_1)
        parent.mysignal.emit(self.radio_1.objectName())                        # +++ mysignal
        self.lay.addWidget(self.radio_2)
        parent.mysignal.emit(self.radio_2.objectName())                        # +++ mysignal


class MyChild(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)                                          # +++ mysignal

    def __init__(self, num=None, parent=None):
        super(MyChild, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("myChild_{}".format(num)) 

        self.parent = parent                                                   # +++
        self.mysignal.connect(self.myDict)                                     # +++ mysignal

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)                               

        self.rad = MyRadio(self)

        self.label.setText( "LABEL_{} <-> {}".format(num, self.objectName()) )
        self.label.adjustSize() 
        self.label.setObjectName("label_{}".format(num))
        print(f' label.parent=`{self.label.parent().objectName()}`, label.objectName=`{self.label.objectName()}`\n')        
        self.label.move(50+num*200, 11)

    def myDict(self, rb):                                                       # +++ !!!
        print(f' _myDict -> `{rb}`')
        self.parent._myDict[rb] = self.label


class MyParent(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("myParent")

        main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        main.setStyleSheet('background: red;')
        main.setObjectName(u"main")
#        main.resize(100, 100)
        main.move(50,50)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(main)
        self.group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)

        self._myDict = {}                                                         # +++ !!!

        for x in range(2) :
            wid = MyChild(x, self)
            lay.addWidget(wid.rad)
            self.group.addButton(wid.rad.radio_1, 0)
            self.group.addButton(wid.rad.radio_2, 1)
        self.group.buttonToggled.connect(self.fun)

    def fun(self, but, state):
        if state:
            print(f'\n\t but.objectName=`{but.objectName()}`')
            print(f'\t but.text=`{but.text()}`')
            self._myDict[but.objectName()].setText(f'{but.objectName()}')          # +++  
            self._myDict[but.objectName()].adjustSize()                            # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    par = MyParent()
    par.resize(400, 170) 
    par.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код интересный но можете ответить мне. Не усложняет ли его то, что для его роботы приходится создавать список `_myDict` 
после создавать `pyqtSignal` который записывает в него objectname кнопок, связывать его с нужным label а после брать objectname кнопки и запускать нужный виджет внутри `_myDict`?

Comment: @orlatym нет, не  усложняет